# Installing perlbrew: Failed to retrieve patchperl executable

Tags: macports, perlbrew

When I try to install perlbrew on [Mac OS X v10.9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks) and [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts), this is what happens:

```
~$ curl -L http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0   315    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  1020  100  1020    0     0    649      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  3217

## Download the latest perlbrew

## Installing perlbrew
perlbrew is installed: ~/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew

perlbrew root (~/perl5/perlbrew) is initialized.

Append the following piece of code to the end of your ~/.bash_profile and start a
new shell, perlbrew should be up and fully functional from there:

    source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc

Simply run `perlbrew` for usage details.

Happy brewing!

## Installing patchperl

ERROR: Failed to retrieve patchperl executable.

~$
```

I then removed `~/perl5/perlbrew` and tried:

```
~$ curl -L http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash -x
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0   315    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  1020  100  1020    0     0    693      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  5368
+ PERLBREWURL=https://raw.github.com/gugod/App-perlbrew/master/perlbrew
+ '[' -z /var/folders/7l/nhyscwy14bjb_sxr_t2gynpm0000gn/T/ ']'
+ cd /var/folders/7l/nhyscwy14bjb_sxr_t2gynpm0000gn/T/
+ LOCALINSTALLER=perlbrew-14023
+ echo

+ type curl

+ PERLBREWDOWNLOAD='curl -f -sS -Lo perlbrew-14023 https://raw.github.com/gugod/App-perlbrew/master/perlbrew'
+ echo '## Download the latest perlbrew'
## Download the latest perlbrew
+ curl -f -sS -Lo perlbrew-14023 https://raw.github.com/gugod/App-perlbrew/master/perlbrew
+ echo

+ echo '## Installing perlbrew'
## Installing perlbrew
+ chmod +x perlbrew-14023
+ /usr/bin/perl perlbrew-14023 self-install
perlbrew is installed: ~/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew

perlbrew root (~/perl5/perlbrew) is initialized.

Append the following piece of code to the end of your ~/.bash_profile and start a
new shell, perlbrew should be up and fully functional from there:

    source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc

Simply run `perlbrew` for usage details.

Happy brewing!

+ echo '## Installing patchperl'
## Installing patchperl
+ /usr/bin/perl perlbrew-14023 -f -q install-patchperl

ERROR: Failed to retrieve patchperl executable.

+ clean_exit 1
+ '[' -f perlbrew-14023 ']'
+ rm perlbrew-14023
+ exit 1
~$
```

I'm stuck on the first step. How can I get perlbrew installed properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can disable certificate checking. The following worked fine for me:

```
echo "check-certificate = off" >> ~/.wgetrc

perlbrew install-patchperl
perlbrew install-cpanm
```

Happy brewing!

Answer (score 3):

Perlbrew installs cleanly for me (also on Mac OS X 10.9.1).

There is an issue report ([here](https://github.com/gugod/App-perlbrew/issues/341)) that it is worth you reading through. It seems likely to be an issue with your version of [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) coupled with GitHub HTTPS URLs. There are a couple of things worth trying:

1. `curl -kL http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash`  
   (`-k` allows insecure [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) connections)
2. Install patchperl manually:

   ```
   curl -kL https://raw.github.com/gugod/patchperl-packing/master/patchperl > ~/perl5/perlbrew/bin/patchperl`
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Based on a suggestion of @jm666, I tracked down the problem source (at least one of them).

What I did:

- Removed perlbrew: `rm -rf ~/perl5/* ~/.perlbrew`
- Completely removed `macports`
- Installed a fresh `macports package`

And I tried installing my usual MacPorts and after every installed port, started a new terminal/shell and tried installing `perlbrew`.

After I installed the `wget` port, the perlbrew installation failed (installing the patchperl). After uninstalling the `wget` port, perlbrew installed again OK.

For the log, installing wget:

```
$ sudo port install wget
--->  Computing dependencies for wget
--->  Dependencies to be installed: gnutls libidn libtasn1 nettle p11-kit curl-ca-bundle desktop-file-utils glib2 libffi popt libxslt libxml2 xz libgcrypt libgpg-error pcre bzip2 libedit
--->  Fetching archive for libidn
--->  Attempting to fetch libidn-1.26_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libidn
--->  Attempting to fetch libidn-1.26_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libidn
--->  Installing libidn @1.26_0
--->  Activating libidn @1.26_0
--->  Cleaning libidn
--->  Fetching archive for libtasn1
--->  Attempting to fetch libtasn1-2.11_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libtasn1
--->  Attempting to fetch libtasn1-2.11_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libtasn1
--->  Installing libtasn1 @2.11_0
--->  Activating libtasn1 @2.11_0
--->  Cleaning libtasn1
--->  Fetching archive for nettle
--->  Attempting to fetch nettle-2.6_1.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/nettle
--->  Attempting to fetch nettle-2.6_1.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/nettle
--->  Installing nettle @2.6_1
--->  Activating nettle @2.6_1
--->  Cleaning nettle
--->  Fetching archive for curl-ca-bundle
--->  Attempting to fetch curl-ca-bundle-7.34.0_0.darwin_13.noarch.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/curl-ca-bundle
--->  Attempting to fetch curl-ca-bundle-7.34.0_0.darwin_13.noarch.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/curl-ca-bundle
--->  Installing curl-ca-bundle @7.34.0_0
--->  Activating curl-ca-bundle @7.34.0_0
--->  Cleaning curl-ca-bundle
--->  Fetching archive for libffi
--->  Attempting to fetch libffi-3.0.13_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libffi
--->  Attempting to fetch libffi-3.0.13_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libffi
--->  Installing libffi @3.0.13_0
--->  Activating libffi @3.0.13_0
--->  Cleaning libffi
--->  Fetching archive for glib2
--->  Attempting to fetch glib2-2.38.2_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/glib2
--->  Attempting to fetch glib2-2.38.2_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/glib2
--->  Installing glib2 @2.38.2_0
--->  Activating glib2 @2.38.2_0
--->  Cleaning glib2
--->  Fetching archive for popt
--->  Attempting to fetch popt-1.16_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/popt
--->  Attempting to fetch popt-1.16_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/popt
--->  Installing popt @1.16_0
--->  Activating popt @1.16_0
--->  Cleaning popt
--->  Fetching archive for desktop-file-utils
--->  Attempting to fetch desktop-file-utils-0.15_1.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/desktop-file-utils
--->  Attempting to fetch desktop-file-utils-0.15_1.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/desktop-file-utils
--->  Installing desktop-file-utils @0.15_1
--->  Activating desktop-file-utils @0.15_1
--->  Cleaning desktop-file-utils
--->  Fetching archive for xz
--->  Attempting to fetch xz-5.0.5_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/xz
--->  Attempting to fetch xz-5.0.5_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/xz
--->  Installing xz @5.0.5_0
--->  Activating xz @5.0.5_0
--->  Cleaning xz
--->  Fetching archive for libxml2
--->  Attempting to fetch libxml2-2.9.1_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libxml2
--->  Attempting to fetch libxml2-2.9.1_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libxml2
--->  Installing libxml2 @2.9.1_0
--->  Activating libxml2 @2.9.1_0
--->  Cleaning libxml2
--->  Fetching archive for libxslt
--->  Attempting to fetch libxslt-1.1.28_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libxslt
--->  Attempting to fetch libxslt-1.1.28_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libxslt
--->  Installing libxslt @1.1.28_0
--->  Activating libxslt @1.1.28_0
--->  Cleaning libxslt
--->  Fetching archive for p11-kit
--->  Attempting to fetch p11-kit-0.20.1_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/p11-kit
--->  Attempting to fetch p11-kit-0.20.1_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/p11-kit
--->  Installing p11-kit @0.20.1_0
--->  Activating p11-kit @0.20.1_0
--->  Cleaning p11-kit
--->  Fetching archive for gnutls
--->  Attempting to fetch gnutls-3.1.10_1.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/gnutls
--->  Attempting to fetch gnutls-3.1.10_1.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/gnutls
--->  Installing gnutls @3.1.10_1
--->  Activating gnutls @3.1.10_1
--->  Cleaning gnutls
--->  Fetching archive for libgpg-error
--->  Attempting to fetch libgpg-error-1.12_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libgpg-error
--->  Attempting to fetch libgpg-error-1.12_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libgpg-error
--->  Installing libgpg-error @1.12_0
--->  Activating libgpg-error @1.12_0
--->  Cleaning libgpg-error
--->  Fetching archive for libgcrypt
--->  Attempting to fetch libgcrypt-1.5.3_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libgcrypt
--->  Attempting to fetch libgcrypt-1.5.3_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libgcrypt
--->  Installing libgcrypt @1.5.3_0
--->  Activating libgcrypt @1.5.3_0
--->  Cleaning libgcrypt
--->  Fetching archive for bzip2
--->  Attempting to fetch bzip2-1.0.6_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/bzip2
--->  Attempting to fetch bzip2-1.0.6_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/bzip2
--->  Installing bzip2 @1.0.6_0
--->  Activating bzip2 @1.0.6_0
--->  Cleaning bzip2
--->  Fetching archive for libedit
--->  Attempting to fetch libedit-20121213-3.0_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libedit
--->  Attempting to fetch libedit-20121213-3.0_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libedit
--->  Installing libedit @20121213-3.0_0
--->  Activating libedit @20121213-3.0_0
--->  Cleaning libedit
--->  Fetching archive for pcre
--->  Attempting to fetch pcre-8.33_1.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/pcre
--->  Attempting to fetch pcre-8.33_1.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/pcre
--->  Installing pcre @8.33_1
--->  Activating pcre @8.33_1
--->  Cleaning pcre
--->  Fetching archive for wget
--->  Attempting to fetch wget-1.14_5+ssl.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/wget
--->  Attempting to fetch wget-1.14_5+ssl.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/wget
--->  Installing wget @1.14_5+ssl
--->  Activating wget @1.14_5+ssl

To customize wget, you can copy /opt/local/etc/wgetrc.sample to /opt/local/etc/wgetrc and then make changes.

--->  Cleaning wget
--->  Updating database of binaries: 100.0%
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors: 100.0%
--->  No broken files found.
```

perlbrew `curl -kL http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash` failed with

```
ERROR: Failed to retrieve patchperl executable.
```

Uninstalling the wget port:

```
$ sudo port uninstall wget
--->  Deactivating wget @1.14_5+ssl
--->  Cleaning wget
--->  Uninstalling wget @1.14_5+ssl
--->  Cleaning wget
$
$ rm -rf ~/perl5/perlbrew/ ~/.perlbrew/
$ curl -kL http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0   315    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  1020  100  1020    0     0   1551      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1551

## Download the latest perlbrew

## Installing perlbrew
perlbrew is installed: ~/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew

perlbrew root (~/perl5/perlbrew) is initialized.

Append the following piece of code to the end of your ~/.bash_profile and start a
new shell, perlbrew should be up and fully functional from there:

    source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc

Simply run `perlbrew` for usage details.

Happy brewing!

## Installing patchperl

## Done.
```

Conclusion: **Something** go wrong with a combination of MacPorts' `wget` and `perlbrew`.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped changing the `PATH` environment variable - disable [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts) by commenting out the next line.

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

or similar in your `~/.profile`.

Something doesn't play nicely from the MacPorts binaries in `/opt/local/bin` with `perlbrew`.

For example, with enabled `macports`, for the

```
perlbrew self-upgrade
```

you will get

> Unable to detect version of new perlbrew!

with disabled `macports` in a PATH will get correctly:

```
Your perlbrew is up-to-date.
```

and like.

After installing `perlbrew`, and your perlbrew's version of Perl and (ofc) sourcing the perlberw's `bashrc` you can return the PATH - only don't forget comment out every time when you want use `perlbrew` itself. And the

```
source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
```

should be **after** the `macports` PATH setting.

*At least, on my installation - maybe your problem has another roots...*

Answer (score 0):

Check your PATH order. Watch out for macports PATHs getting added later to the search than the perlbrew paths. I just cleaned out a bunch of "helper" addenda PATHs in .bash_profile, .profile and put everything in .bashrc, in the order in which I want to search, i.e. perlbrew before macports before system. If you are left joining your path, i.e. PATH=/foo:/bar:$PATH, go in reverse order in your start up file than you want the search path to accrue. Below I add the macports /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin to the path before the perlbrew path elements.

```
perl-swine:~ $ cat .bash_profile
[ -r /Users/perl-swine/.bashrc ] && source /Users/perl-swine/.bashrc
# $PATH in .bashrc


perl-swine:~ $ cat .profile
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]
then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
# $PATH in .bashrc


perl-swine:~ $ cat .bashrc 
yadda
yadda moving along to the important part
yadda
# macports
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
#python
PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:$PATH
PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:$PATH
#perlbrew
source /Users/perl-swine/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
export PATH;

perl-swine:~ $ echo $PATH
/Users/perl-swine/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/perl-swine/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.2/bin:/Library
/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
/2.6/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt
/X11/bin:/usr/texbin

perl-swine:~ $ which perl
/Users/perl-swine/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.2/bin/perl

perl-swine:~ $ perlbrew list
  perl-5.16.0 (5.16.3)
* perl-5.18.2



perl-swine:~ $ which perl5
/opt/local/bin/perl5

perl-swine:~ $ which perl5.12
/opt/local/bin/perl5.12

perl-swine:~ $ sudo port list installed | grep perl
perl5                          @5.12.4         lang/perl5
perl5.12                       @5.12.4         lang/perl5.12
perl5.16                       @5.16.1         lang/perl5.16


perl-swine:bin $ ls /usr/bin/perl*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  58608 Oct 23 00:47 /usr/bin/perl
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  35440 Oct 23 00:54 /usr/bin/perl5.12
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel  35440 Oct 23 00:47 /usr/bin/perl5.16
```